# What's the best way to combine multiple Github repo's while keeping track of them?

Tags: git, github

I want to amalgamate several github repo's into a single "boilerplate" for use by our agency. For example, I want to combine the best practices of Paul Irish' HTML5 Boilerplate with Nicole Sullivan's OOCSS (among many other best practice frameworks).

I'd like to use the H5 boilerplate as a base starter github and then keep track of OOCSS within the CSS directory (obviously).

- root (html5 boilerplate starts tracking changes here)

  - css (oocss hub starts here)
  - js (gets updated from H5B)
    .... and so on

Periodically, I'd want to update this new github with the changes from both - and subsequent other hubs as and when. Is it possible to do with while maintaining my original folder structure? I've tried forking the H5B into a new hub and then creating a new "remote" inside the CSS folder but so far it hasn't worked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [submodules](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial).

Answer (score 2):

I've heard good things about [git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree). It's a feature-rich alternative to the submodules mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions, already mentioned:

- git submodules (git's native)
- git subtree (additional, extended library)

See this post for more details about including external library repositories to your project:

- http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/258-Git-Subtree-Merging-Guide.html